# Make an icon blink wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I have an icon.

```
 imgstop.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

How can I make the icon to be appear to be blinking ?

I tried the codes below:

```
  public void blinkIconStopHide()
        {
            blinkTimerStop.Enabled = true;
            blinkTimerStop.Interval = 15000;
             imgstop.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
             blinkTimerStop.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tick_to_hideStop);  
        }
        private void tick_to_hideStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            blinkIconStopShow();
        }  
        public void blinkIconStopShow()
        {
            blinkTimerStop.Enabled = true;
            blinkTimerStop.Interval = 15000;
            imgstop.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            blinkTimerStop.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tick_to_showStop);   
        }
        private void tick_to_showStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            blinkIconStopHide();
        }
```

But nothing seems to be blinking on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will let your Icon blink each second by toggeling visibility. By changing the Interval of the DispatcherTimer you can *blink* the icon faster or slower.

```
DispatcherTime _blinkTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

public void StartBlinking() {
  _blinkTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  _blinkTimer.Elapsed += ToggleIconVisibility;
  _blinkTimer.Start();
}

public void StopBlinking() {
  _blinkTimer.Stop();
  _blinkTimer.Elapsed -= ToggleIconVisibility;
}

private void ToggleIconVisibility(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  imgstop.Visibility = !imgstop.Visibility;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

What about animating the icon/image?

XAML

```
<BeginStoryboard>
   <Storyboard>
       <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                        Duration="0:0:0.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                        AutoReverse="True"/>
   </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

C#

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.From = 1;
da.To = 0;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
da.AutoReverse = true;
da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
yourimage.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, da);
```